# Valgrind error on glib hash table

Tags: c, hashtable, valgrind, glib

I'm programming in C and I can't get rid of the valgrind error.

```
char* s; // this one has some value...
GHashTable* hash = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);
char** lineSplit = g_strsplit(s, "\n", -1);
// temp is in a loop, but for this example I only insert one (still error)
char** temp = g_strsplit(lineSplit[0], " ", 2);
g_hash_table_insert(hash, temp[0], temp[1]); // yes the temp length > 1
g_strfreev(temp);
g_strfreev(lineSplit);

// now, valgrind won't give me an error so far
// but when I call lookup, then valgrind finds an error in 
// inserting temp[0] values
gpointer t = g_hash_table_lookup(hash, "some value"); // don't have to free
if(!strcmp(t, "bla")) printf("yihaa");

g_hash_table_destroy(hash);
```

The Valgrind error is:

> Invalid read of size 1.

(happens 4 times in the loop)

> ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

I'm running Valgrind with:

> env G_DEBUG=gc-friendly G_SLICE=always-malloc valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./program

Thanks in advance! - Hope you can help me.

Comment: Not familiar with glib, but I suspect that you should not free the pointers you have inserted into the hash table...I doubt their content is copied into any other buffers.

Comment: `Invalid read of size 1` narrows the culprit down to the read of a *character*, not a pointer. So if your example is compete, the only type `char` I see is `temp[0]` or `temp[1]`. Double check your validation of `temp`, otherwise, I think @EugeneSh. probably nailed it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, one can attempt to read a single character via an invalid pointer, and that very well could happen during the course of a hash lookup if one of the hash keys has been freed.  That is, I don't think the size of the invalid read is in any way inconsistent with Eugene's diagnosis.

Comment: @EugeneSh. is right! Now it's a matter of implementation. By freeing temp right before I destroy the table, I manage to be valgrind error free :). But now I have to somehow keep track of all the "temps" (using loop of unknown size) and free them afterwards.

Comment: You don't have to; just `g_free(temp)` instead of `g_strfreev(temp)` (so you only free the container array, not the strings), and create your hash table with `g_hash_table_new_full(g_str_hash, g_str_equal, g_free, g_free)` (so glib will free the strings when the hash table is destroyed).

Comment: @JohnBollinger, agreed, though my thought in that case was you would need a valid pointer to attempt a character read and produce an *invalid read of size 1*. If the pointer has already been freed, then I would expect an *invalid read X bytes beyond a block previously freed*. I don't claim total `valgrind` foo, but using the size of invalid read has always provided a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I was able to fix it from @EugeneSh. and nemequ comments. EugeneSh., you can write your comment as an answer.
Thanks again!